# Get the data for the entering selection in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

With d3 the selection returned by *.enter() is special in that it is only a placeholder for coming elements. Unfortunately this means I can not get the data related to the entering elements using *.data() (as is possible with *.exit().data()).

I'm currently in a situation where the timing of several transitions is dependant on the content of the entering elements before these elements are initialised.

My question is thus: How do I obtain an array of the data objects that will be linked to the entering elements in a data join, before these have been instantiated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the data structures inside the selection directly. At the top level, there's a single element array. The element contains the placeholder elements with the data bound to them for the enter selection. You just need to iterate over those elements.

```
var enterData = selection.data(data)
    .enter()[0].map(function(d) { return d.__data__; });
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9tzu8w3f/).